# Can't change adapter host with Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I've read Ember docs about this and I know that I have to use custom RESTAdapter and set it to App.Store. I did it and it changes namespace but, it doesn't work with host (it still makes request to current domain).

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  host: 'https://api.example.com',
  namespace: 'kraken'
});

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  adapter: App.ApplicationAdapter
});


App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('game');
  }
});
```

And request is being made to current domain instead to https://api.example.com

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:8080/kraken/games
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the latest Ember Data (1.0.0-beta.*) you don't have to specify a store.

Just specify the adapter, that should be enough.

Comment: What do you mean? How should I tell Ember which adapter to use, when there is no store?

Comment: I got this. Migrated to ember data 1.0.0 and it started working.

Answer (score 2):

example of it working:

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/zemurayabi/1/edit?js,console,output

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
  // put your routes here
});

App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  host: 'https://api.example.com',
  namespace: 'kraken'
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('game');
  }
});

App.Game = DS.Model.extend({

});
```

please note, as the ajax requests goes to nowhere it will actually error. But it will attempt the correct non-local url.

Comment: In fact, after migration to ember-data 1.0.0 it started working as it should.